# jqgrid: set column header tooltips differing from the column label

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, tooltip

As I understand there are a few ways to set different column header tooltips.
Currently my solution is to set the tooltips with jQuery .attr().

My question would be whether is there a concise way to store the custom header tooltip values inside colModel?

Would make easier to oversee the different options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer on your question depends on the version of jqGrid, which you use, and the fork. I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/) fork since the end of 2014 and have implemented `headerTitle` property in `colModel` starting with the version [4.9.1](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README491.md#the-following-bug-fixes-and-small-new-features-are-implemented-in-the-version-491) (the current version is 4.14.4).

One can specify the tooltip of the column header as the value of `headerTitle` property of `colModel`.

Comment: We are using the rather old 4.7 version. Don't ask, old codebase, awkward legacies... :)

Comment: @Tylla: old 4.7 version don't have the feature and you have to use `jQuery.attr()` or `setLabel`, which do the same. By the way I use 4.x.y conversion for versions because I try to hold maximal compatibility with 4.x versions. You can just change 3 lines of HTML code to load free jqGrid from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). You will see whether any problems exist at all. By including [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) 4.x CSS, for example, and the option `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` you can improve the visibility.

Comment: @Tylla: See [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) for more simple example of the usage. In general you should understand that version 4.7 is old and it's dead. There are two main forks of old jqGrid: free jqGrid and commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). I recommend you to decide which one from the forks you want to use in the future and to migrate to the latest version of the fork.

Comment: Yes we know that 4.7 is ancient. We are right now considering to upgrade to free jqGrid for a few other reasons/features anyway, so it seems that headerTitle will be the way forward.